# How to get id from associated relation rails?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, relationship, ruby-on-rails-6

Can i get an id from associated relation?
for example i have relation between user and skill through user_skill

In User model, i write like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many ::skills, through: :user_skills
end
```

In UserSkill model

```
class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can call them like this

```
User.find(1).skills
```

but there is no user_skill id in there.
how to include id of user_skill? because everytime i call

> User.find(1).skills

it will be like this

```
[#<Skill id: 3, name: "Google Analytics", description: "Google Analytics\r\n", created_at: "1970-01-04 11:20:00.000000000 +0000", updated_at: "1970-01-04 11:20:00.000000000 +0000", category: "software">, #<Skill id: 8, name: "Adobe After Effect", description: "Test", created_at: "2022-08-21 02:58:25.561498000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-08-21 02:58:25.561498000 +0000", category: "software">, #<Skill id: 1, name: "Microsoft Office", description: "Word, Excel, PowerPoint", created_at: "1970-01-02 03:46:40.000000000 +0000", updated_at: "1970-01-02 03:46:40.000000000 +0000", category: "software">]
```

Comment: Why do you need the `UserSkill#id`? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I need to manipulate data on user_skills table like update and delete, i think easiest way to do this is finding them by id, can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
user_skills = User.find(1).user_skills.include(:skill)

user_skills.each do |user_skill|
  user_skill.id      #=> the user_skill id
  user_skill.skill   #=> the actual skill
end
```